# When using the Xceed DateTimePicker in a WPF C# app, why does the value only update once when using OneWay binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker, xceed

If I try to use the Xceed `DateTimePicker` control (v4.0.1 currently) and use a `OneWay` binding to a property on my view model, I find that the value in the control only updates once (the first time it changes after the initial value) but any subsequent changes to the view model property do not cause the `DateTimePicker` value to update (at least visually).

To be clear, the binding appears to work at least twice: the initial value is properly set from the view model *and* the first time the view model property is updated, the updated value is properly shown in the control. However, all subsequent updates to the property have no effect on the value of the control: it's like it gets "stuck" after the first change. To see if I'm completely off-base with my WPF binding expectations, I also defined a plain `TextBox` with a `OneWay` binding right next to the `DateTimePicker` in the XAML bound to the same property on the view model and it updates completely as expected -- no getting stuck. It would seem that using `OneWay` binding works there as I was expecting.

Here is a snippet of the relevant XAML:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker
    x:Name="DateTakenPicker"
    Value="{Binding Path=DateTaken,Mode=OneWay}"
/>
<TextBox
    x:Name="DateBox"
    TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
    Text="{Binding Path=DateTaken,Mode=OneWay}"
/>
```

and the relevant view model property:

```
private DateTime? _dateTaken = null;
public DateTime? DateTaken
{
    get { return _dateTaken; }
    set
    {
        if (_dateTaken != value)
        {
            _dateTaken = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
...
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Whenever code changes the `DateTaken` property, the value shown in the `TextBox` **always** changes to match, but the date shown in the `DateTimePicker` only shows the value initially and then after the first change. The second through N changes only ever change the value in the text box.

I also verified that if I change the binding on the `DateTimePicker` to be `TwoWay` then it behaves as expected: that is, **all** changes are **always** properly reflected in the `DateTimePicker`, not just the first change. But... why does that only happen with `TwoWay` binding and not `OneWay`?

Also to be clear, I'm never clicking into or typing into or even fiddling with the `DateTimePicker` control, only causing the code to change the `DateTaken` value and observing the effect on the controls.

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `if (_dateTaken != value)` to `if (! Equals (_dateTaken, value))`

Comment: @MickyD I doubt this will make any difference as DateTime implements the (in)equality operators `==` and `!=`.

Comment: @KlausGütter OK.  What about for the situations described in the Remarks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1#System_Object_Equals_System_Object_System_Object_)?

Comment: Your analysis seems correct at first sight and this might be a bug in DateTimePicker. As source code is availabe at [github](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit), you could debug this issue and file a bug report there.

Comment: @MickyD The equality operators on `Nullable<T>` are [lifted operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators). If I read everything correcty, this is equivalent to the `Equals` behaviour when any (or both) parameters are null.

Comment: @KlausGütter _"lifted operators"_ - thanks.  _I learnt something new today_ :)